# Could someone help me to improve the proof writing?

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, article-writing

I will prove the following claim. I'm not a native English speaker. Could someone help me to improve the writing?

A regular pseudocompact Moore space is ccc and first countable.

> Prove: I will cite a corollary to prove it. The corollary is this: A feebly compact, perfect space is ccc and first countable. Pseudocompactness implies feebly compactness; A Moore space is perfect. So a regular pseudocompact Moore space is ccc and first countable.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there’s no need to mention regularity: by definition every [Moore space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_space_%28topology%29) is regular. There’s also no real reason to mention first countability, since it’s trivial that every developable space is first countable: anyone who knows what a Moore space is will also know that Moore spaces are first countable. I would replace *pseudocompact*, which is generally of interest only for Tikhonov spaces, with *feebly compact*. The lemma should be simply:

> **Lemma.** Every feebly compact Moore space is ccc.
>
> **Proof.** Since every Moore space is perfect, this is an immediate consequence of Proposition $2.3$ of Jack R. Porter & R. Grant Woods, ‘Feebly compact spaces, Martin’s axiom, and “diamond”’, *Topology Proceedings* $9$, Nr. $1$ ($1984$), pp. $105$-$121$: *A feebly compact perfect space is ccc*.

Comment: Roger Moore is my third favorite Bond.

Comment: @Asaf: Well, this Moore was an R. Moore, but his R. was for Robert. (He’s my academic grandfather.)

Comment: Well it still beats the Moor Space in Spain. ;-)